# how to set the video height/width in afterglow player on html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, afterglow

I just to make my video responsive using the `afterglow` plugin for `HTML`. It occupies the whole space on my screen even if I already set the `width` and `height`, I don't want to make it like that. Please see my code below:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/afterglowplayer@1/dist/afterglow.min.js"></script>

<video class="afterglow" id="myvideo" width="640" height="480" src="https://www.srv33.convertinmp4.com/download.php?v=LDD1HwKwTg9TeQc1w9q47JAq6dyuqV3v" data-skin="dark"></video>
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, afterglow is made to be responsive. It will take your width and height and calculate the video's ratio from it. It will then scale the video element to fit into it's parent element while maintaining the ratio.

So in order to really have it responsive and be able to style it, just wrap it into a container and set width and height on the container.

EDIT: Just saw that your width and height are 640 - 480. Keep in mind that afterglow will maintain this ratio when scaling. So if you want 16-9 (widescreen), make the width and height of the player match this ratio.

Also, you could disable responsive scaling by using `data-autoresize="none"` on the player. But this is not advised, as it makes it way harder to scale for mobile devices. Going with a wrapper and CSS styling is the better way.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/afterglowplayer@1/dist/afterglow.min.js"></script>

<div class="videowrapper">
    <video class="afterglow" id="myvideo" width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.srv33.convertinmp4.com/download.php?v=LDD1HwKwTg9TeQc1w9q47JAq6dyuqV3v" data-skin="dark"></video>
</div>

<style>
    .videowrapper{
        width: 400px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: It is not responsive now

Comment: It should be. Make the container have `position:relative` if it isn't. Also, here is the documentation on responsive scaling: http://docs.afterglowplayer.com/docs/responsive-scaling. If things don't work out for you, post a link to the page, I'll look into it.

Comment: The documentation only says the disabling of the responsiveness. However, I used `%` for the width of the wrapper instead of `px`. It is now responsive.

Comment: Perfect. I'll add the information on the wrapper there.

Comment: Ooh!  I didn't notice that you're the author of afterglow .

Comment: No problem. Keep in mind that afterglow relies on many other projects, like video.js., who do a great job building video functionality for the web. :-)

Comment: That's great!  :)